# Вывести таблицу знакогенератора

Tags: java, c++, c

Можно ли вывести матрицу знакомест и изображений символов (таблица знакогенератора) програмно (через функции и библиотеки)?

Comment: Так вроде понятнее. Коллеги, если кому-то всё ещё непонятно, пожалуйста **оставляйте комментарии, задавайте уточняющие вопросы**.

Comment: @NickVolynkin стало лучше, но я бы не сказал, что понятнее. Вывести где? Попробуйте вывести один символ, за ним другой и т.д.

Comment: знакогенератор был в древних-древних досах. Сейчас знакогенератор используетс в основном только в микроконтроллерах с маленькими экранами. А в виндах/линуксах/маках давно используют шривты с растеризаторами.

Comment: Вот эту таблицу нужно найти < pp.vk.me/c626826/v626826077/4544c/kGfVLPMjEjc.jpg >;